# jQuery CSS not updating / creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery & AJAX for this. But I have an input field that calls to a JS method `updateLayout1()`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control jscolor class=mt-4 jscolor-active" name="module_background" onchange="updateLayout1('module_background', this.value, token)">
```

And this is my JS method.

```
function updateLayout1(key, value, csrf = token) {
    let layout = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/_ajax/updateLayout.php",
        data: {layout, key, value, csrf},
        dataType:"json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            if(data.error) {
                toastr.error(data.error);
            } else if (data.success) {
                toastr.success(data.success);
                let val = '#' + value + " !important";
                let ele = $(data.css);

                switch (data.css_type) {
                    case "background":  ele.css("background-color", val);
                    case "color":       ele.css("color", val);
                    case "border":      ele.css("border-color", val);
                    case "hyperlink":   ele.css("color", val);
                    default:            ele.css("color", val);
                }


                console.log(ele);
                console.log("Works :: Type: " + data.css + " Value: " + $(data.css).css(data.css_type));
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Now when this method is called it returns a `success` string that tells the user that the query went through and then returns `css` and `css_type` that look like this.

```
css: .panel-body, css_type: background
```

And in debugging, jQuery is finding the element that I'm selecting but isn't executing my changes. I've tried without the switch case and just doing one at a time but to no luck. It also does return the `value` being `78FF7C` for example.

Comment: Can you post what's in `data` when you `console.log` it?

Comment: `let val = value + " !important";` where is this `value` defined? is it coming from data?

Comment: @vinayakj, it's one of the function's arguments

Comment: `78FF7C` is not a valid `background-color`/`color` css value, `#78FF7C` is

Comment: @PatrickEvans You are correct, I did update the post to have the # and still doesn't work. It doesn't even get to the .panel-body despite it reading all of its properties perfectly fine.

Comment: @PatrickEvans sry didnt see that there

Comment: You are missing `break` statements in each of your `cases`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add  Break after each case.
2. Your `ele` should be `ele = $("#"+ data.css);`
3. You may try using `ele.attr("style","background-color:"+val+" !important;");`
    or  `ele.prop("style","background-color:"+val+" !important;");`
4. `ele.css()` method does not support `!important` in the code.
5. All the best :)

Comment: _"Your `ele` should be `ele = $("#"+ data.css);`"_, no OP's `data.css` contains a class selector: `.panel-body`. Attempting to prepend the id selector would make it not work.

Answer (score 0):

> http://api.jquery.com/css/
>
> Note: .css() ignores !important declarations. So, the statement
>
> $( "p" ).css( "color", "red !important" )
>
> does not turn the color of all paragraphs in the page to red. It's strongly advised to use classes instead; otherwise use a jQuery plugin.

So as the docs say, since you are appending !important to the style jQuery is ignoring it, meaning not setting it.

Simply remove it from the code and it will work. Should not need it here anyways as inline styles already have a higher specifity by itself. If you are applying classes that use `!important` and are trying to override that, you should refactor your code to be based on specifity instead of `!important`.

```js
//ignored
$('#one').css('background-color','#00ff00 !important');
//not ignored
$('#two').css('background-color','#00ff00');
```

```css
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
</div>
<div id="two">
</div>
```